# Redefine \S - problem with indices

Tags: math-mode, indexing

Why are the subscripts placed under the letters and not in the right bottom corner like usual?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\let\origS\S\renewcommand{\S}{\ifmmode\mathop{\mathsf{S}}\else\origS\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:decS}
\S=\S_0 \oplus\S_1 .
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because the `\mathop` turns the "S" into an operator like `\lim` and `\sum`.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? What mathematical object is `\S` suppose to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `\nolimits` to force `\mathop` not to treat the operator like, for example, `\sum`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\let\origS\S\renewcommand{\S}{%
  \relax\ifmmode\mathop{\mathsf{S}}\nolimits\else\origS\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:decS}
\S=\S_0 \oplus\S_1 .
\end{equation}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}\S\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course the question arises whether we are talking about an operator (in TeX speak, not necessarily mathematically) here in the first place. Maybe `\let\origS\S\renewcommand{\S}{\ifmmode\mathsf{S}\else\origS\fi}` would be more sensible.

Comment: You should try `\begin{pmatrix}\S\end{pmatrix}`.

Comment: @egreg Interesting, though given my logo, you can understand that I am not as shocked as I should be.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your command should be a `\mathop`, the correct redefinition would be

```
\renewcommand{\mathsection}{\operatorname{\mathsf{S}}
```

Redefining `\S` that way is bound to problems, as `\S` is a “robust” command.

If it is not an operator, `\renewcommand{\mathsection}{\mathsf{S}}` would suffice.

You can see the difference in the two examples below (`twocolumn` used just for making a smaller picture). In (1) the symbol behaves like an operator, in (2) it's an ordinary symbol.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand{\mathsection}{\operatorname{\mathsf{S}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:decS}
\S=\S_0 \oplus\S_1 x.
\end{equation}

\renewcommand{\mathsection}{\mathsf{S}}

\begin{equation}
\S=\S_0 \oplus\S_1 x.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]